# How to create a train-val split in custom image datasets using PyTorch?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, pytorch, torchvision

I want to create a train+val set from my original trainset. The directory is split into train and test. I load the original train set and want to split it into train and val sets so I can evaulate validation loss during training using the **train_loader** and **val_loader**.

There's not a lot of documentation about this which explains things clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the answer [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/what-is-the-difference-between-creating-a-validation-set-using-random-split-as-opposed-to-subsetrandomsampler/72462/5?u=theairbend3r).

I've posted it below as well.

======================================================

The data is read using `ImageFolder`. Task is binary image classification with 498 images in the dataset which are equally distributed among both classes (249 images each).

```
img_dataset = ImageFolder(..., transforms=t)
```

#### 1. `SubsetRandomSampler`

```
dataset_size = len(img_dataset)
dataset_indices = list(range(dataset_size))

np.random.shuffle(dataset_indices)

val_split_index = int(np.floor(0.2 * dataset_size))

train_idx, val_idx = dataset_indices[val_split_index:], dataset_indices[:val_split_index]

train_sampler = SubsetRandomSampler(train_idx)
val_sampler = SubsetRandomSampler(val_idx)


train_loader = DataLoader(dataset=img_dataset, shuffle=False, batch_size=8, sampler=train_sampler)
validation_loader = DataLoader(dataset=img_dataset, shuffle=False, batch_size=1, sampler=val_sampler)
```

#### 2. `random_split`

Here, out of the 498 total images, 400 get randomly assigned to train and the rest 98 to validation.

```
dataset_train, dataset_valid = random_split(img_dataset, (400, 98))

train_loader = DataLoader(dataset=dataset_train, shuffle=True, batch_size=8)
val_loader = DataLoader(dataset=dataset_valid, shuffle=False, batch_size=1)
```

#### 3. `WeightedRandomSampler`

> if someone stumbled here searching for `WeightedRandomSampler`, check @ptrblck's answer [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/some-problems-with-weightedrandomsampler/23242/40?u=theairbend3r) for a good explanation of what is happening below.

Now, how does `WeightedRandomSampler` fit in creating train+val set? Because unlike `SubsetRandomSampler` or `random_split()`,  we're not splitting for train and val here. We're simply ensuring that each batch gets equal number of classes during training.

So, my guess is we need to use `WeightedRandomSampler` **after** `random_split()` or `SubsetRandomSampler`. But this wouldn't ensure that train and val have similar ratio between classes.

```
target_list = []

for _, t in imgdataset:
    target_list.append(t)

target_list = torch.tensor(target_list)
target_list = target_list[torch.randperm(len(target_list))]

# get_class_distribution() is a function that takes in a dataset and 
# returns a dictionary with class count. In this case, the 
# get_class_distribution(img_dataset)  returns the following - 
# {'class_0': 249, 'class_0': 249}
class_count = [i for i in get_class_distribution(img_dataset).values()]
class_weights = 1./torch.tensor(class_count, dtype=torch.float) 

class_weights_all = class_weights[target_list]

weighted_sampler = WeightedRandomSampler(
    weights=class_weights_all,
    num_samples=len(class_weights_all),
    replacement=True
)
```